# imhsow in matplotlib doesn't show as same as opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, matplotlib

It seems that matplotlib.pyplot.imhsow(plt.imshow) doesn't show the original picture, does it scale the values of image? I found the difference when using cv2.imhsow and plt.imhsow.

I have two images, which differ in the brightness. However, when using `plt.imshow`, they are shown equally. But it shows correctly when using `cv2.imhow`. Here is the code and images.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img_o = plt.imread('1.jpg')
img = plt.imread('2.jpg')
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('img_o', img_o)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
plt.gray()
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
plt.imshow(img_o)
plt.show()
```

Images used for `imshow`, they are different in brightness.

[image: 1.jpg]
[image: 2.jpg]

When using `cv2.imshow`, they can be shown as the original one.

Images shown by `plt.imshow` are uploaded below. They look exactly same and it seems like `plt.imshow` ignore the brightness of the images.

[image: img]
[image: img]

Comment: Images have been converted into grayscale.

Comment: It will depend on the shape (`img.shape`) and datatype (`img.dtype`) what matplotlib shows. In general, 2D arrays are scaled between their minimum and maximum value. You may provide a [mcve], such that people can find out about your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I made a change to my question. And I upload the images that I used for `imshow`. What's more I also upload the images that shown by `plt.imshow()` which I thought a little strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images are of type uint8 and 48 x 48 pixels in shape. Hence matplotlib's `imshow` will colormap them with the active colormap (`plt.gray()`). The colormap normalization is chosen according to the minimum and maximum of the data. This becomes clear when plotting with a colorbar.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img_o = plt.imread('1.jpg')
img = plt.imread('2.jpg')

fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
plt.gray()
im1 = ax.imshow(img)
fig.colorbar(im1, ax=ax)

im2 = ax2.imshow(img_o)
fig.colorbar(im2, ax=ax2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

From that we see that for the first image white denotes a value of 70, while for the second white is 218. To use the same normalization in both cases, and to be consistent with 8bit images, one may use `norm = plt.Normalize(0,255)`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img_o = plt.imread('1.jpg')
img = plt.imread('2.jpg')

norm = plt.Normalize(0,255)

fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
plt.gray()
im1 = ax.imshow(img, norm=norm)
fig.colorbar(im1, ax=ax)

im2 = ax2.imshow(img_o, norm=norm)
fig.colorbar(im2, ax=ax2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Alternatively, you may duplicate the gray values to all three RGB channels, such that you plot a 48x48x3 pixel array. This will be interpreted as image (as opposed to colormapped data) and shown correctly.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img_o = plt.imread('1.jpg')
img = plt.imread('2.jpg')

img_o = np.dstack((img_o,img_o,img_o))
img = np.dstack((img,img,img))


fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
im1 = ax.imshow(img)
im2 = ax2.imshow(img_o)

plt.show()
```

[image]